# How I can assign multiple elements on a primary table an duplicate the index in the first table in R?

Tags: r, indexing

Hi and thanks for reading me. I have a primary table which contains a value "1" in the column "val" and I want to add two values in another column, duplicating the value of val, but what I have tried has not worked. For example:

Primary table:

```
x <- tibble(
  val = 1,
  val2 = NA
)
```

I tried with:

```
x$val2[x$val == 1]  <- c(5,3)
```

but return's me an error message. I even try with:

```
library(zeallot)
x$val2[x$val == 1]  %<-% c(5,2)
```

but only assign the firs value. My expected result should be the following:

```
val  val2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     5
2     1     2
```

Is there a way to get this result?

#### UPDATE

using reframe the code works only if I have 1 row in "val" but if I add more returns me an error message. For example:

```
x <- tibble(
  val = c(1,2,3),
  val2 = NA
)
reframe(x, val, val2=c(5, 2))

Error in `reframe()`:
! Can't recycle `val2 = c(5, 2)`.
Caused by error:
! `val2` must be size 3 or 1, not 2.
ℹ An earlier column had size 3.
```

and if try using index like:

```
reframe(x, val[val == 1], val2=c(5, 2))
```

only returns 2 rows:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  `val[val == 1]`  val2
            <dbl> <dbl>
1               1     5
2               1     2
```

The expected result for me should be:

```
 val  val2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     5
2     1     2
3     2    NA
4     3    NA
```

Comment: whats the error message? in your real data will you have to do this for multiple `val`s

Comment: this one: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` and yes, there are many cases in my real data where I need to insert multiple values

Comment: try `reframe(x, val, val2 = c(5, 2))`

Comment: @Onyambu only works for the first one ): if the table have more rows with different numbers in "val" didn't work. Thank for your answer

Comment: What do you mean with *more rows*?? Show an example in your question

Comment: Done, thanks. I update the question

Comment: where do the replacement values come from for val2?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for a join?

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- tibble(
  val = c(1,2,3)
)

y <- tibble(
  val = 1,
  val2 = c(5, 2)
)

x |> left_join(y)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(val)`
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>     val  val2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5
#> 2     1     2
#> 3     2    NA
#> 4     3    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>